duckdb cli with utf8 from windows - what setting to use national strings?
i explore duckDb under windows 10 (winget install DuckDB.cli)
$ duckdb --version # v1.1.2 f680b7d08f

my goal is to select from xlsx (or csv with utf-8 encoding file)
and i'm faced with the fact that I cannot use national symbols
i start dickDb from git bash:
$ chcp.com 65001
$ duckdb
D .utf8

and my problem is that i can't use national text literals
D select 'test'; -- ok
┌─────────┐
│ 'test'  │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ test    │
└─────────┘

D select 'тест'; -- waiting enter "';" 
';
┌─────────┐
│   ''    │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│         │
└─────────┘

Subj!
if enter "chcp.com 1251" in git bash (w/o .utf8 in DuckDB) than
text literal interpreted correctly, with pure pseudographics:
D select 'тест';
ЪДДДДДДДДДї
і 'тест'  і
і varchar і
ГДДДДДДДДДґ
і тест    і
АДДДДДДДДДЩ

but real problem is that select from csv/excel files returns incorrect data:
load spatial; 
SELECT name FROM st_read('GTV.xlsx');
ЪДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДї
і            Name             і
і           varchar           і
ГДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДґ
і ‘вп¦Є  Minifix EC02/16/TE01 і
і ‘вп¦Є  Minifix EC02/16/TE03 і
і ‘вп¦Є  Minifix D15/5 18¬¬   і
і ѓў®§¤м 1е16                 і
і ѓў®§¤м 1,6е25               і
і ѓў®§¤м 3е100                і

SELECT * FROM st_read('GTV.csv'); -- encoded in utf8 -> same output


D .utf8
D SELECT name FROM st_read('GTV.csv');
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│            Name             │
│           varchar           │
├─────────────────────────────┤
│ Стяжка Minifix EC02/16/TE01 │
│ Стяжка Minifix EC02/16/TE03 │
│ Стяжка Minifix D15/5 18мм   │

correct output, but i can't use:
SELECT name FROM st_read('GTV.xlsx') where name like '%Шуруп%';

because cli interpretor waiting enter "';" and ignores national chars(
